# locally compact Hausdorff space which is not second-countable

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, second-countable

I'm trying to find an example of a space that is Hausdorff and locally compact that is not second countable, but I'm stuck. I search an example on the book Counterexamples in Topology, but I can't find anything.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Here](http://www.austinmohr.com/spacebook) is a nice web site for such questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Y$ be an uncountable set, let $p$ be a point not in $Y$, and let $X=\{p\}\cup Y$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\{\{x\}:x\in Y\}\cup\{X\setminus F:F\text{ is a finite subset of }Y\}\;;$$

then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a Hausdorff, locally compact, compact topology $\tau$ on $X$ that is not second countable. It isn’t even first countable: $p$ has no countable local base. $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is the [one-point compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification#The_one-point_compactification) of the discrete space $Y$. (Of course $Y$ itself is also an example, but it’s merely locally compact; $X$ is also compact.)

You can make examples with even nicer properties. For instance, $Y\times[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, locally compact, and locally connected but not second countable. The [closed long ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) has all of those properties and is in addition connected, path connected, and locally path connected. Its one-point compactification loses path connectedness but gains compactness.

Comment: Ow thank You for your help!

Comment: @Charles: You’re welcome!

Comment: It is also example of a compact hausdroff space space that is not second countable . Nice! Thank you.

Comment: @Noobmathematician: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Discrete spaces are locally compact.